# Can Virtual Classes in C++ have Member Variables?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a purely virtual class, can I do something like this in C++:

```
class ITreatable
{
    public:
       bool hasBeenTreated;           // <- Can this be here?
       virtual bool Treat() = 0;
};
```

And if not, how can I ensure that classes which inherit `ITreatable` have a member variable called `hasBeenTreated`? Is that possible? Is there some kind of best practice that avoid having to do this / advises against it?

Thanks

Edit: Also how would I define a constructor for such a class?

Edit2: I understand that public member variables are bad practice, I'm just wondering if the design in general is a good idea in C++ or not.

Comment: this is C++ not Java! ;) there is no such thing as a *pure interface* in C++ (if there is, it's artificial - i.e. developer enforced). As such, you can have whatever you want in your base class in C++, including member variables. However use proper encapsulation.... like you would a normal constructor for any other class...

Comment: @Nim yes I understand and I've never really used Java :) But I was reading some Java code and was wondering if I can "mimic" Java interfaces in C++.

Comment: @Peter R., nothing stops you from attempting to mimic Java from C++, just be aware that any restrictions (like the one above) will not be enforced by the compiler.

Comment: @Peter R. why? Again go back to my original point, you are programming in C++, why mix concepts? If the base class allows you to store commonality - why do you want all your derived classes to implement the same stuff - just so that it can be like Java?

Comment: @Nim I'm just trying to experiment. This is not real production code, it just crossed my mind and I thought I'd get some feedback. Maybe if I use interfaces then a lot of the code can be reused and easily extended, don't you think?

Comment: @Peter R. *interfaces* are not designed to encourage code re-use (or extension), an *interface* is exactly that, it provides a set of methods that are exposed by a given object. A base class in an inheritance hierachy achieves a different purpose - it allows you to have common functionality in the base with the derived implementing additional functionality. Key point is that you can use the base *type* like you would an *interface*, so then what is the purpose of a *pure interface*?...

Comment: ...the only situation is decoupling, you want to decouple certain components and ensure they work with specific *interfaces* implemented by the same object, fine, but unlike Java, in C++ this is done with multiple inheritance - which is a whole another kettle of fish...

Comment: @Nim I always thought of an interface as a kind of virtual base class. I might be missing something but what is the use of an interface if all it does is expose methods? Why not always use a virtual base class?

Comment: @Peter R. we're going around in circles here.. :) You wanted to "mimic" Java `interfaces` in C++, and I told you that the concept is artificial in C++ (it can be done, a class with all pure virtual methods and multiple-inheritance), but you should only really look into it for cases where you need strict decoupling and you don't want to expose any of your logic via the *interface* to the consumer. Where it doesn't matter (I'd hazard majority of cases), always use what you have above, a base class to hold all the commonality - don't burden the derived classes.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Absolutely.

Strictly speaking, there is no such thing as a "virtual class". I understand that you are using the term to mean a class constructed of only data members and virtual member functions.

Consider that only functions can be virtual; if you wish for data members to be accessed polymorphically, you must do this through functions. Thus, use virtual getter/setter functions, and keep your data members private.

Comment: +1 For getting what I actually meant :) I am actually implementing this but it crossed my mind and I thought I'd get some feedback on the usefulness/correctness of such an approach. It also seems to me that I am misunderstanding the concept of an interface :/

Comment: @PeterR: No problem! If it helps, interfaces generally specify only functions. (Actually, that's the case even if it doesn't help :P)

Answer (score 9):

Acordingly to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755792.aspx) an interface has these characteristics:

- An interface class (or struct) must be declared within a namespace
  and may have public or private accessibility. Only public interfaces
  are emitted to metadata.
- The members of an interface can include properties, methods, and
  events.
- All interface members are implicitly public and virtual.
- Fields and static members are not permitted.
- Types that are used as properties, method parameters, or return
  values can only be Windows Runtime types; this includes the
  fundamental types and enum class types.

So I would response to your question with

> **NO** if you want an interface

and

> **Yes** if you just use abstract classes, but as the others say, make them private and use public getters and setters

Comment: The cleanest answer!

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

There is no concept of a "pure virtual" class in C++, merely abstract classes with virtual members.

As for whether there is a best practice, I would say that the biggest practice that should be followed in this example is not to use public variables. Rather, have a setter/getter defined in the base class that modifies a private variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I think the hasBeenTreated variable should prob be protected but I was wondering if it was a good idea to follow such a design in general.

Comment: @Peter R., make it private with a setter & getter. You never want your classes to completely lose control of their own variables.

Answer (score 3):

That is possible. C++ doesn't have interfaces enforced by the language, so your example acts like normal class definition without any special rules.

It's considered bad practice to declare variables as public in classes. You might want to make it private and declare accessor/mutator for it or declare it as protected.

Comment: Even protected is frowned upon when it comes to variables. It has all the same problems as public, except it only affects base classes.

Comment: @Tomalak, its "affects". Affect is most commonly used as a verb, and effect is most commonly used as a noun. :P http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/affect-versus-effect.aspx

Comment: @Stargazer712: I can't believe I did that. Must have been drunk. Apologies.

Comment: @Tomalak, I wasn't really confident on the difference between the two before you made me check myself, so thank you :)